# The result of .each in view, Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have some problem with my .each loop. The result of .each is displayed like json in my view:

[image: some description]
Here is a code from my controller:

```
def index
  @articles = Article.all
end
```

And here is my view:

```
<h1>Всі статті</h1>
<%= link_to "Нова стаття", new_article_path %>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Заголовок</th>
        <th>Вміст</th>
        <th colspan="2"></th>
    </tr>

    <%= @articles.each do |article| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= article.title %></td>
            <td><%= article.text %></td>
            <td><%= link_to "Переглянути", article_path(article) %></td>
            <td><%= link_to "Редагувати", edit_article_path(article) %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Loops return their array. The <%= is outputting the return of the loop. Remove the =.

Renders array:

```
 <%= @articles.each do |article| %>
```

Does not render array:

```
 <% @articles.each do |article| %>
```

Answer (score 2):

`<%= @articles.each do |article| %>` should be `<% @articles.each do |article| %>` don't print the iterator

Answer (score 2):

remove the the '=' sign in `<%= @articles.each do |article| %>` --> `<% @articles.each do |article| %>`

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure I've run into this same problem a number of times.

This line right here `<%= @articles.each do |article| %>` shouldn't have the equal sign.

Answer (score 0):

You are displaying the `each` loop in the erb view. Each loops should not have the `=` sign, or you will display the entire collection.

So turn this:

`<%= @articles.each do |article| %>`

Into this:

`<% @articles.each do |article| %>`