# Why are these active record query results appearing in my view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I created a table to display ActiveRecord query results. Results display correctly in table however there are other results appearing above table.

Query in controller:

```
@plan = Plan.joins(:leads).
    where.not(leads: {plan_id: nil}).
    group('plan_name, plan_price_cents').
    select('plan_name, plan_price_cents*count(plan_id)/100 AS total_revenue')
```

View:

```
<table class>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Plan Name</th>
  <th>Revenue</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<%= @plan.each do |plan| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= plan.plan_name %></td>
    <td>$<%= plan.total_revenue %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
```

I expect to just view the table and the results. But I see the table and `[#<Plan id: nil, plan_name: "4 Lines">, #<Plan id: nil, plan_name: "T-Mobile One">, #<Plan id: nil, plan_name: "3 Lines">]` above the table.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/35327169/479863 and many others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this line

```
<%= @plan.each do |plan| %>
```

To this

```
<% @plan.each do |plan| %>
```

The `=` shows values so it is causing that loop to output the values to the view instead of looping through it.